# Add photo to new ParseUser

Tags: android, parse-platform, photo

I'm using Parse for Android. I want to add photo to newly created `ParseUser`. Here is a sample code:

```
if(company.getBackgroundImage()!=null) {

                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(c.getResources(),R.drawable.launcher);
                // Convert it to byte
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                // Compress image to lower quality scale 1 - 100
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();
                // Create the ParseFile
               final ParseFile file = new ParseFile("androidbegin.png", image);
               user.put("alfa1",file);
            }

            user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback(){
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException arg0) {
                    if (arg0 == null) {


                        Log.i("LOG_OUTPUT", "Data saved in sever");
                    } else {
                        Log.e("LOG_OUTPUT", arg0.getCode() + "Data not saved in server");

                    }
                }
            });
```

The file isn't uploaded!

It isn't uploaded and the error code is -1;
I'm doing the signup phase, I don't understand how to create a new User with his photo. I've already converted the file, in fact myImage is `byte[]` and it works for simple `ParseObject`.
Thanks

Comment: Changed title, added tags, question format.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that a signup adds data.

What happens if you do:

```
        user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback(){
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException arg0) {
                if (arg0 == null) {


                    user.put("alfa1",file);
                    user.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback(ParseException e) {
                        if (e != null) {
                            Log.e("LOG_OUTPUT", "error saving user", e);
                            return;
                        }

                        Log.i("LOG_OUTPUT", "Data saved in sever");

                    });
                } else {
                    Log.e("LOG_OUTPUT", "error signing up user", e);

                }
            }
```

If the user is already logged in at this point in your code, then you should omit signUpInBackground.

Answer (score 0):

Here the correct way:

```
background.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    // If successful add file to user and signUpInBackground
                    if(e == null) {
                        Log.d("Sono qui image: ", "sono qui");
                        user.put("Background", background);
                        user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(com.parse.ParseException e) {
                                if (e == null) {
                                    //ok registrazione
                                    Log.d("Ok: ", "Registration ok");

                                }
```

Comment: So you weren't uploading the image, were you?